# Given a knight on an infinite chess board that moves randomly, what's the expected number of distinct squares it reaches in 50 moves?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, geometric-probability

I was asked this in an interview and wasn't sure how to frame the answer. Basically as in the question you have a knight on an infinite chess board and it chooses one of its valid 8 moves uniformly at each move. After 50 moves, the question was to give (as tight as possible) a lower and upper bound on the expected number of distinct squares it reached.

I got as far as realizing that the knight must live in a 200x200 square, and that it can only reach half of the squares (since it must end at the same colour as it started). However this doesn't really address the randomness aspect of the question.

Comment: Obvious upper bound is 50. A better upper bound is to note that the knight can always go directly back to where it just came from, so the average is at most 2+(7/8)(49) (the first position is unique, and the first jump will be to a unique position, and any other jump has a 1/8 chance to be going back to where the knight just was). Getting any rigorous lower bound at all seems difficult; it seems like you need some understanding of what a knight-cycles looks like, other than the simple case of simply reversing an earlier move.

Comment: Hmmm. Just in terms of an interview: I would expect that answering: "I am not sure I could answer that in a half-hour but here's an approach" would win you a lot of respect. I suppose it's the type of interview you were sitting in but I am not sure I can imagine going to an interview and not answering with some variant of that. Did you have access to a computer during this interview? Was this question typed? +1. A good math question regardless of it's context in this interview.

Comment: Perhaps one reason that I ask for context is that I don't think it's a particularly cool programming question. So if you had access to your favorite programming language I would think you could simulate this whole thing pretty quickly and answer with some empirical data.

Comment: For some more context it was a quantitative trading interview, so the goal is less to get the exact answer and more to see how tight your lower / upper bound is. Like an answer of "between 2 and 50" would be a bad answer, for example. The question is more phrased like "If you could buy and sell this market, how many moves would you buy at vs sell at?"

Comment: @Mason What about simulating an exact answer? :)

Comment: Well... The question I would like to ask is about the expected number of distinct squares visited after $n$ moves for arbitrary $n$. Let's call this $E[n]$ and then we should consider $E[n]/n$. Can we find the $\lim_{n\to \infty} E[n]/n$?

Comment: @Aaron Very interesting problem. For which company/position was the interview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exact solution can be acquired by computing $d_{x, y}(n)$ which is the number of distinct paths reaching $(x, y)$ for the first time after $n$ steps. The total number of paths $p_{x,y}(n)$ which contains $(x, y)$ after $n$ steps then has relationship:

$$p_{x, y}(n) = 8p_{x, y}(n-1) + d_{x, y}(n)$$

Using this we can express the expected number of distinct squares per path after $n$ steps, as counting the total number of distinct squares for each path and the total number of distinct paths crossing a square is equivalent when summing over all paths or all squares.

Then, saving some computation time we find by four-fold rotational symmetry that the expected number of distinct squares per path after $n$ steps is equivalent to:

$$1 + \frac{4}{8^{n}}\sum_{(x > 0, y \geq 0)} p_{x, y}(n)$$

How do we compute $d_{x, y}(n)$? We do it using matrices $M_{x, y}(n)$ which are initially zero everywhere except at $(0, 0)$ where they have value $1$. Then we apply a kernel convolution encoding the possible knight moves:

$$M'_{x, y}(n)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}\star M_{x, y}(n-1)$$

Then $d_{x, y}(n)$ is the element at $(x, y)$ in $M'_{x, y}(n)$, and we set $(x, y)$ in the above matrix to zero to get $M_{x, y}(n)$ for future computation. Because we repeatedly set that coefficient to zero after each iteration it is that we count the number of distinct paths reaching $(x, y)$ for the *first* time, rather than all the paths that reach $(x, y)$ after $n$ steps. Unfortunately this does mean that for all possible $(x, y)$ we must compute these matrices a total of $n$ times.

I've implemented the above in Rust:

```
use gmp::mpz::Mpz;
use gmp::mpq::Mpq;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn knight_step(d: Vec<Mpz>, w: i32) -> Vec<Mpz> {
    let mut nd = vec![Mpz::new(); (w*w) as usize];
    for &(dx, dy) in &[(-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)] {
        let rx = (-dx).max(0)..(w-dx).min(w);
        let ry = (-dy).max(0)..(w-dy).min(w);
        for x in rx {
            for y in ry.clone() {
                let cx = x + dx;
                let cy = y + dy;
                nd[(x*w + y) as usize] += &d[(cx*w + cy) as usize];
            }
        }
    }

    nd
}

fn count_distinct(n: usize) -> Mpz {
    let w = 4*n + 1; // Size of a side of the board.
    let z = 2*n; // Origin is at (z, z);

    let mut total_distinct = Mpz::new();
    for x in z+1..w {
        println!("{}", x);
        let subproblems: Vec<_> = (z..w).collect::<Vec<usize>>().par_iter().map(|y| {
            let mut d = vec![Mpz::new(); w*w];
            d[z*w + z] = Mpz::from(1);
            let mut p = Mpz::new();

            for _ in 0..n {
                d = knight_step(d, w as i32);
                p = 8i64*p + &d[x*w + y];
                d[x*w + y] = 0.into();
            }

            p
        }).collect();

        for s in &subproblems {
            total_distinct += 4i64*s;
        }
    }

    total_distinct
}

fn main() {
    let n = 50;
    let q = Mpq::ratio(&count_distinct(n), &Mpz::from(8).pow(n as u32));
    println!("{}", q + &1.into());
}
```

Giving the exact result:

$$\frac{455207943209697100946821497094086408107332219}{11150372599265311570767859136324180752990208} \approx 40.82446$$

Comment: Well... The question I would like to ask is about the expected number of distinct squares visited after $n$ moves for arbitrary $n$. Let's call this $E[n]$ and then we should consider $E[n]/n$. Can we find the $\lim_{n\to \infty} E[n]/n$?

... Would it be very easy for you to write out a few more values of $E[n]/n$? Just to see if this thing seems to have a nice limit?

Comment: @Mason It's too slow to conclude anything about the limit.

Answer (score 2):

My experiments in Mathematica give $40.06$ as the average number of distinct cells (I've done several tries for $100'000$ trials).

I'm counting the initial square though, because it makes the program more simple.

I wouldn't know how to approach this problem theoretically, but it's simple enough to do tests. Knight's moves shift it $2$ cells in one direction and $1$ cell in the other direction. Which gives us $8$ options on an infinite board.

Here's the code I used and a sample of the results:

```
Tm = 100000;
Ds = Table[1, {t, 1, Tm}];
Do[
  Nm = 50;
  P = Table[{0, 0}, {n, 1, Nm}];
  M = {{1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {-1, -2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-2, 
     1}, {-2, -1}};
  Do[R = RandomInteger[{1, 8}];
   P[[n + 1]] = P[[n]] + M[[R]], {n, 1, Nm - 1}];
  Ds[[t]] = CountDistinct[P], {t, 1, Tm}];
Histogram[Ds]
N[Mean[Ds], 10]
```

[image]

Note that the distribution is asymmetrical.

Increasing the number of steps to $100$ I get around $77.36$. Which agrees well with the $4/5$ ratio.

Made $1'000'000$ tests with $100$ steps and got $77.38$, so the numbers don't change much for larger samples.

I wonder how we can get the $4/5$ estimate theoretically.

---

In general, this falls under the topic of random walks and their return probabilities.

---

**Edit** It would be better to set $N_m=51$ in my program, then it corresponds to $50$ moves and the resulting average $40.82$ fits well with the other answer.

Comment: I don't believe your simulation is correct. I have posted an exact answer, which also coincides with [a simulation](https://gist.github.com/orlp/482076a1348f91df1105c0bc84f71d8e) I've written.

Comment: @orlp, our answers differ by less than $1$, so I wouldn't worry. My program actually counts $49$ moves, not $50$

Comment: I like your approach, especially the way you have displayed the results in a histogram, so one has a sense of the spread in addition to the average.  Suggestion: If you're going to post the results of a Monte Carlo simulation, it helps to set the random number seed at the start of the simulation.  This makes it possible for others to reproduce your results exactly.  In Mathematica, the function to set the random number seed is SeedRandom[n].

Comment: @orlp, if I set $Nm=51$ in my program, I get a value around $40.82$ which corresponds to your exact solution. Cheers and +1 to you

Comment: @awkward, good idea, thanks